# Oracle Select from dual not working

Tags: select, oracle11g

```
  DECLARE
  NUMBEROFITEMS NUMBER;
  ORDERID       NUMBER;
BEGIN
  ORDERID := 7;

  SUNIL.PROCEDURE_WITH_OUT_PARAMETERS(NUMBEROFITEMS, ORDERID);--this increments the orderid by 1

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(NUMBEROFITEMS || ' for orderid ' || (ORDERID + 1));

  SELECT (NUMBEROFITEMS || ' for orderid ' || (ORDERID +1)) AS 'Result' FROM DUAL;
END;
```

I am running the above PL/SQL block in a query tool or Oracle. When I try to execute, it gives an for the last SELECT saying that 'an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT'.  If I comment out the last SELECT then it executes without errors.
In the procedure being called, 'NumberOfItems' is an out parameter and 'OrderID' is an in parameter.

**My question**: What is wrong with the last SELECT in above PL/SQL block?

Comment: "*What is wrong with the last SELECT in above PL/SQL block?* - as the error message told you: you need an `INTO` clause to store the result of that query somewhere.

Comment: So in Oracle one cannot do things like 'SELECT expression from dual'? I am a SQL Server person and new to Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `PL/SQL` block, the selected columns in a `select` statement must be assigned to variables.

In this case, you can define a variable

```
foo VARCHAR(1024);
```

Then

```
SELECT (NUMBEROFITEMS || ' for orderid ' || (ORDERID +1)) into foo FROM DUAL;
```